# SQL query is not executing.. -ORACLE take long time and no results

Tags: sql, oracle12c

```
select count(*)
from siebel.s_srv_req
where trunc(created)>='25-Sep-2017'
and trunc(created)<='25-Sep-2017'
and X_MBL_AREA_LIC is not null
and sr_cat_type_cd <> 'Trouble Ticket';
```

I'm trying to execute above sql in my oracle db and its not giving results.
If i execute this as below it works fine. Created is an indexed column.

```
select count(*)
 from siebel.s_srv_req
    where trunc(created)>='25-Sep-2017'
    and trunc(created)<='25-Sep-2017'
```

when i see the execution plan it gives below error
[image]

What should i need to be done to work this fine. This is working fine in my test environment

Comment: you are filtering on records that are created on or after 25 Sep AND created on or before 25 Sep.  The only intersect in those sets is 25 Sep.  So why not use TRUNC(created) = TO_DATE('25/09/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: You have two queries. One is working fine and another is giving problem. You need to share both the execution plans. Also FTS is not an error. It is just an access path to the table. If possible share the table DDL along with its indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `TRUNC`, the index may not be used by optimizer. If you are sure that you don't have data in the table for dates beyond `'25-Sep-2017'`,

you may use

```
WHERE created >=  DATE '2017-09-25'
```

Otherwise use,

```
WHERE created >=  DATE '2017-09-25'  AND  created  < DATE '2017-09-26'
```

or if you are using `SYSDATE`,
`created >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) and  created  <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `X_MBL_AREA_LIC`  and `sr_cat_type_cd`  fields are indexed.

Also if you can change the values of sr_cat_type_cd column to integer values it could work faster. Now you make a string comparison for every record.

Comment: @Amal - just because the indexes helped, don't igore Kaushik Nayak's answer, which is giving you excellent advice. First, even though it is somewhat common practice, giving a date in the form of a string, without `to_date` or a date literal (as Kaushik used) is plain wrong. And then, putting your column within `trunc()` will kill any chance at using an index. Re-write the inequalities as shown in that answer.